# how to make the normalization factor for the color scale in jointplot?

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I'm making a jointplot in Seaborn and want to make a normalization color scale like this example, [image]

What code can achieve this goal?

In the past, I’ve tried on using `cmap` in `sns.joint` but no change

```
 import seaborn as sns
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 import pandas as pd
 import os
 os.chdir("e:\\test")
 df=pd.read_excel('try.xlsx')
 sns.jointplot(x="gpm", y="station", data=df, kind="kde")
<seaborn.axisgrid.JointGrid object at 0x00000231D90BAC18>
 plt.show()
 sns.jointplot(x="gpm", y="station", data=df)
<seaborn.axisgrid.JointGrid object at 0x00000231DFB680B8>
 plt.show()
```

I did get any change

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample image, it seems you want a `kdeplot` rather than a `jointplot`, so you can use `sns.kdeplot` directly, plotting onto subplots using matplotlibs's subplots, or using seaborn's FacetGrid.

In `sns.kdeplot`, you can use `cmap` to specify a colormap, and `cbar=True` and `cbar_kws` to control the color bar.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(0,10,(100,2)), columns=['a','b'])
sns.kdeplot(data=df['a'], 
            data2=df['b'], 
            shade=True, 
            shade_lowest=False, 
            cmap='YlOrBr', 
            cbar=True, 
            cbar_kws=dict(orientation='horizontal'))
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much .i will try it. In the figure ,"The number in the lower-right corner of each plot shows the normalization factor for",how to do for the color scale

Comment: @missinPYTHON Look into [`plt.text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html).